# Cython automatic unrolling loop

Tags: python, loops, cython

I am trying to accelerate a part of a Python code in which I have the following code:

```
for i in range(n):
   for j in range(m):
       for (sign,idx) in [(a,b),(c,d),(e,f),(g,h)]:
           array[idx,i] += sign * something
           array[idx,j] += sign * somethingElse
```

where a,b,c... are relatively complex expressions.

If I manually unrol for inner for loop by writting:

```
for i in range(n):
   for j in range(m):
           sign,idx = a,b
           array[idx,i] += sign * something
           array[idx,j] += sign * somethingElse
           sign,idx = c,d
           array[idx,i] += sign * something
           array[idx,j] += sign * somethingElse
           sign,idx = e,f
           array[idx,i] += sign * something
           array[idx,j] += sign * somethingElse
           sign,idx = g,h
           array[idx,i] += sign * something
           array[idx,j] += sign * somethingElse
```

The code runs 4x faster... But copy-pasting seems like a bad idea.

My question: can it be done automatically at compile time?

Comment: What's `a`, `b` etc? My guess is this has to do with Cython being able to infer the type of `sign` and `idx` and the difference will go away if you explicitly type them.

Comment: I should probably have written a longer bit of code. The variables a and b comes from function calls (and both the variables "sign/idx" and the functions have types).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that this is indeed a problem of typing: in test1(), I explicitly construct an array "values" while in test2() I construct this array each time.

```
def test1():
    cdef int i
    cdef int value
    cdef int values[4]
    cdef double sum = 0
    values[:] = [1,2,3,4]
    for i in range(1000000):
        for value in values:
            sum += values[j]
    return sum

def test2():
    cdef int i
    cdef int value
    cdef double sum = 0
    for i in range(1000000):
        for value in [1,2,3,4]: 
            sum += value
    return sum
```

The first version is roughly 3 times faster:

```
%timeit test1()
4.4 ms ± 44.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit test2()
13.3 ms ± 44.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```